# using triggers to update Values

Tags: stored-procedures, triggers, sql-server-2000, sql-job

I'm trying to enhance the performance of a SQL Server 2000 job. Here's the scenario:
Table `A` has max. of 300,000 rows. If I update/delete the 100th row (Based on the insertion time) all the rows which has been added after that row, should update their values. Row no. 101, should update its value based on row no. 100 and row no. 102 should update its value based on the row no.101's updated value.  e.g.

**Old Table:**

```
ID...........Value  
100..........220  
101..........(220/2) = 110  
102..........(110/2)=55  
......................
```

Row No. 100 updated with new value: 300.

**New Table**

```
ID...........Value  
100..........300  
101..........(300/2) = 150  
102..........(150/2)=75  
......................
```

The actual values calculation is more complex. the formula is for simplicity.

Right now, a trigger is defined for update/delete statements. When a row is updated or deleted, the trigger adds the row's data to a log table. Also, a SQL Job is created in code-behind after update/delete which fires a stored procedure that finally, iterates through all the next rows of table `A` and updates their values. The process takes ~10 days to be accomplished for 300,000 rows.

When the SP gets fired, it updates the next rows' values. I *think* this causes the trigger to run again for each SP update and add these rows to the log table too. Also, The task should be done in DB-side as requested by customer.

**To solve the problem:**
Modify the stored procedure and call it directly from the trigger. The stored procedure then drops the trigger and updates the next rows' values and then creates the trigger again.

- There will be multiple instances of the program running simultaneously. if another user modifies a row while the SP is being executed, the system will not fire the trigger and I'll be in trouble! Is there any workaround for this?
- What's your opinion about this solution? Is there any better way to achieve this?

Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure what "Row no. 101, should update its value based on row no. 100 and row no. 102 should update its value based on the row no.101's updated value." actually means. Could you add an actual example of the type of updating involved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, about the update process. I understand, your procedure is simply calling itself, when it comes to updating the next row. With 300K rows this is certainly not going to be very fast, even without logging (though it would most probably take much fewer days to accomplish). But what is absolutely beyond me is how it is possible to update more than 32 rows that way without reaching the maximum nesting level. Maybe I've got the sequence of actions wrong.

Anyway, I would probably do that differently, with just one instruction:

```
UPDATE yourtable
SET @value = Value = CASE ID
                       WHEN @id THEN @value
                       ELSE @value / 2 /* basically, your formula */
                     END
WHERE ID >= @id
OPTION (MAXDOP 1);
```

The `OPTION (MAXDOP 1)` bit of the statement limits the degree of parallelism for the statement to 1, thus making sure the rows are updated sequentially and every value is based on the previous one, i.e. on the value from the row with the preceding ID value. Also, the `ID` column should be made a clustered index, which it typically is by default, when it's made the primary key.

The other functionality of the update procedure, i.e. dropping and recreating the trigger, should probably be replaced by *disabling and re-enabling* it:

```
ALTER TABLE yourtable DISABLE TRIGGER yourtabletrigger

/* the update part */

ALTER TABLE yourtable ENABLE TRIGGER yourtabletrigger
```

But then, you are saying the trigger shouldn't actually be dropped/disabled, because several users might update the table at the same time.

All right then, we are not touching the trigger.

Instead I would suggest adding a special column to the table, the one the users shouldn't be aware of, or at least shouldn't care much of and should somehow be made sure never to touch. That column should only be updated by your 'cascading update' process. By checking whether that column was being updated or not you would know whether you should call the update procedure and the logging.

So, in your trigger there could be something like this:

```
IF NOT UPDATE(SpecialColumn) BEGIN
  /* assuming that without SpecialColumn only one row can be updated */
  SELECT TOP 1 @id = ID, @value = Value FROM inserted;
  EXEC UpdateProc @id, @value;
  EXEC LogProc ...;
END
```

In `UpdateProc`:

```
UPDATE yourtable
SET @value = Value = @value / 2,
    SpecialColumn = SpecialColumn /* basically, just anything, since it can
                                     only be updated by this procedure */
WHERE ID > @id
OPTION (MAXDOP 1);
```

You may have noticed that the UPDATE statement is slightly different this time. I understand, your trigger is FOR UPDATE (= AFTER UPDATE), which means that the @id row is already going to be updated by the user. So the procedure should skip it and start from the very next row, and the update expression can now be just the formula.

In conclusion I'd like to say that my test update involved 299,995 of my table's 300,000 rows and took approximately 3 seconds on my not so very fast system. No logging, of course, but I think that should give your the basic picture of how fast it can be.

Comment: @Andriy M: Very, very informative. Thank you. I'll try your suggestion in a few days (since it's a bit more complex than I stated, and it's in production env., it needs to be done very carefully) and see what happens. Thanks again.

Comment: @Andriy M: One more thing: A SQL Job is defined in code-behind to call the SP. Is it really necessary? or do you suggest just calling the sp directly from trigger or use SQL jobs to call it?

Comment: @Kamyar: Could you please elaborate on how the job knows which rows are to be updated? I mean, if a user updates the row with `ID=100`, how are you telling the job to update all the other rows with IDs after 100 (based on the value from ID=100)?

Comment: That seems like a dangerous assumption that `OPTION (MAXDOP 1)` will force sequential processing *in ID order*. SQL server provides no such guarantee. It *might* follow the clustered index order, if you're lucky, but there's no guarantee that the clustered index is ID.

Comment: @Damien: I thought just as well that ID might not be the clustered index. That's why I said it should be made so.

Comment: But it's still not guaranteed that SQL server will process the update in the clustered index order.

Comment: @Damien: What different order could (might) the server choose in this particular case?

Comment: If the table was a partitioned one, it might select a partition it knows will definitely satisfy the condition before one that straddles the condition. I don't have insight into the internals of SQL Server, but it used to have an optimization for selects (back on 2000 Enterprise, I believe) that if a table scan was already in progress for another connection, a subsequent table scan could piggy back on it - could MS have extended this to work with an UPDATE following a SELECT? - I don't know. But since MS are free to make optimizations in the future also, I wouldn't write code that *assumes*

Comment: @Andriy M: The trigger inserts every updated row in a table called `VgLog`. The job is performed on every row which is in `Vglog` and rows after that (based on primary-auto incrementing `ID` column) and then deletes the row from `Vglog`.

Comment: @Kamyar: If you start calling the SP from the trigger, it will change user experience. With every update a user will have to wait until the SP has completed its work. On the other hand, if the SP is fired from the SQL Agent job, the user doesn't know when the SP is actually finished (if I'm not missing anything).

Comment: @Anbdriy M: Yes. The only *very dirty* solution I can think of is to modify some flag in a table at the end of SP and check it every x seconds in the code-behind to verify that the process is finished. Any other way? :-s

Comment: @Kamyar: Setting the flag doesn't seem to me a dirty approach. Maybe checking for the flag every x seconds *is* somewhat dirty. But if that implies that the user always waits till the end of the process (to see when it ended), then I would probably call the SP from the trigger, not from the job. In any case, I wouldn't set the flag in the SP itself, if you meant that. If I was calling the SP from the job, then I would set the flag in the job script, directly after the SP call.

Comment: @Andriy M: I don't want to call the SP directly because the user might change many rows in a few seconds and I'd like to call sp when it's done. I've thought about other approaches but I'm pretty sure using jobs is the only way to go. But you're right. setting the flag in job seems more reasonable. Thank you for being very generous and answering all my questions. I would have +10 your answer if I could.

Comment: @Kamyar: Calling it from the job seems positively better than from the trigger if a user may update more than one row at once. Please consider Damien's comments as well and give this solution a proper testing. It's likely that your job will often be performing multiple serial updates, and if SQL Server 2000 is indeed so crafty when it comes to query optimisation, then some of Damien's misgivings might turn out true.

Answer (score 1):

Big theoretical problem here.  It is always extremely suspicious when updating one row REQUIRES updating 299,900 other rows.  It suggests a deep flaw in the data model.  Not that it is never appropriate, just that it is required far far less often than people think.  When things like this are absolutely necessary, they are usually done as a batch operation.

The best you can hope for, in some miraculous situation, is to turn that 10 days into 10 minutes, but never even 10 seconds.  I would suggest explaining thoroughly WHY this seems necessary, so that another approach can be explored.

Comment: Thanks! Actually, I'm hoping for 10 minutes too. and the customer will be completely satisfied with it. It's an accounting software written in .Net 2. the Cardex prices need to get updated when a voucher is updated. the update should be performed row by row as I mentioned.

Comment: @Kamyar, well, um, what I meant was that if it *seems* like all of those Cardex prices need to get updated when a voucher is updated, that is the design flaw.  I'd wager good money that requirement could be designed out while still satisfying the customer.  But, we'll leave that for another day.  Glad you found your answer.